# Expect same character again

Tags: bash, expect

expect prompt again to pass different command

```
spawn bash
sleep 1
expect "$"
send -- "whoami\r"
expect '$'
send -- "hostname\r"
```

This script only does the first command

Comment: Expect uses the [Tcl language](http://www.tcl.tk/) which has different syntax from Bash. If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can use [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate my problem, how to expect the same character again later in an expect script

Comment: you need to learn Tcl's syntax first or you cannot really use Expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious problem is that in the second `expect` command you use single-quotes `'` but these have no meaning in Tcl syntax, so the string you are expecting becomes singlequote-dollar-singlequote, which of course does not match your bash prompt.  See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8 for the forms of quoting which Tcl accepts.

Comment: In Expect, `expect "$"` is always a no-op.